# Como obtener el valor de un objeto map en dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo esta constante Map> categoriesBg

```
const categoriesBg = {
    // Key:    Value
    'all': {
      'color1' : Color(0xffffffff),
      'color2' : Color(0xffffffff)
    },
    'apparel': {
      'color1' : Color(0xffFFAE4E),
      'color2' : Color(0xffFF7676)
    },
    'beauty': {
      'color1' : Color(0xff4EFFF8),
      'color2' : Color(0xff76BAFF)
    },
    'shoes': {
      'color1' : Color(0xffB4FF4E),
      'color2' : Color(0xff2FC145)
    },

  };
```

y quiero tener el valor de uno de los colores por ejemplo
el de  all => color1 o el de shoes =>color1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes acceder directamente  al map.

```
//Accede a color1
final color1all = categoriesBg['all']['color1'];

//Para shoes
final color1shoes = categoriesBg['shoes']['color1'];

// Puedes hacer lo mismo para los demás valores
```

A continuación te explico brevemente como funciona los Map, deseguro te servirá en un futuro:

**Que es un Map? :** 
Es un conjunto de llaves y valores. Del cual puedes obtener su valor al utilizar la llave correspondiente.

```
const miMap = {
  'llave1': 'Hola',
  'llave2': 'mundo',
};
```

Como puedes ver en el ejemplo anterior, tenemos un map llamado `miMap`, para poder acceder a sus valores tenemos que hacer uso de las llaves, de la siguiente manera.

```
print(miMap['llave1']);
//resultado: Hola
```

Cómo puedes ver, a diferencia de un arreglo o lista en el cual utilizamos los indexes para acceder a sus valores aquí utilizamos las llaves.

Es bueno que tengas en cuenta que para cada llave habra un único valor asociado, pero recuerda que este valor puede ser un `string`, `number`, `bool`, `lista` e incluso otro `map`.

Si desea saber mas, [Map - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map) te ofrece una idea mas detallada sobre los Map, no es Dart... pero los principios son los mismos.

Saludos.

Comment: si te sirvió puedes marcarla como resuelta

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper, estuve viendo tu respuesta y la quise aplicar a mi caso, pero no me funciono. En mi caso **{"usuarios":[{"id":"12345","nombre":"pepe","apellido":"valencia","grado":"Basica"}]}** como podría extraer el valor de nombre y apellido en variables, algo así como **String t_nombre = {"nombre"}** y **String t_apellido = {"apellido"}**

Comment: @Isabel, hola, si te animas a ser miembro de mi canal de YT, estamos en discord resolviendo todo tipo de dudas :)