# Recorrer Lista anidada y mostrar widgets en flutter

Tags: json, lista, flutter, dart

Como puede Recorrer una lista anidada (nested list) y mostrar widgets en flutter?
Necesito mostrar el main_title en una columna y los titulos de los items en otra

```
var listCats = [
  {
    'main_title' : 'MENS\'S APPAREL',
    'items' : [
      {
        'title': 'T-shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
      {
        'title': 'Shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    'main_title' : 'WOMEN APPAREL',
    'items' : [
      {
        'title': 'Officewear',
        'route' : '/',
      },
      {
        'title': 'Blouse & T-Shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
    ]
  },
];

class _WidgetCats extends StatelessWidget {

  renderCats(listCats) {
    return Column(
      children: listCats.map((item) => 
        Text('main_title'), //Mostrar el titulo principal aqui

         //Mostar items
        Column(
          children: [
            // titulo del item aqui
            Text('title')
          ],
        )
      ).toList()
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: renderCats(listCats),
    );
  }
}
```

al hacerlo asi me sale el error **list dynamic ' is not a subtype of type 'map string dynamic'**

he subido el ejemplo aqui para que se pueda observar que no muestra nada  https://codepen.io/zkmark/pen/VwvKgLe

Comment: Tienes una pregunta en el aire, primero cierra esa antes de continuar : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347331/como-obtener-el-valor-de-un-objeto-map-en-dart

Comment: Podrias leer el [tour]?? recuerda aceptar las respuestas que te dan, para asi obtener mas y mejores respuestas.

Comment: listo marcada, al tratar de recorrer me sale list dynamic ' is not a subtype of type 'map string dynamic' y como se ve en el ejemplo online no se muestra nada https://codepen.io/zkmark/pen/VwvKgLe

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma que funciona

```
var listCats = [
  {
    'main_title' : 'MENS\'S APPAREL',
    'items' : [
      {
        'title': 'T-shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
      {
        'title': 'Shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    'main_title' : 'WOMEN APPAREL',
    'items' : [
      {
        'title': 'Officewear',
        'route' : '/',
      },
      {
        'title': 'Blouse & T-Shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
    ]
  },
];


class _WidgetCats extends StatelessWidget {

  renderCats(listCats) {
    return Column(
      children: listCats.map<Widget>((category) => 
        //Mostar items
        Column(
          children: [
            Text((category['main_title'] != null) ? category['main_title'] : ''),
            Column(
              children: category['items'].map<Widget>((item) => 
                Text((item['title'] != null) ? item['title'] : ''),
              ).toList()
            )
          ],
        )
      ).toList()
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: renderCats(listCats),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: claro hay muchas formas, pero en este caso tu respuesta es incorrecta ya que solo usas Column, cuando tengas muchos items, no podrá scrolear y te saldrá error de overflow, por lo tanto la respuesta que puse es la adecuada, puedes marcarla como resuelta y cerrar la pregunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Para este caso, tienes que tener en cuenta que tienes un listado de listados.

Cada item del listado, tiene sub-items, así que tienes que hacer un doble loop.

Aquí tienes el código corregido, revísalo:

```dart
class _WidgetCats extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget renderCats() {
    return ListView(
      children: listCats
          .map(
            (item) => Column(children: [
              Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(
                      item['main_title'])), //Mostrar el titulo principal aqui

              //Mostar items
              Column(
                  children: (item['items'] as List)
                      .map(
                        (subItem) =>
                            // titulo del item aqui
                            Text(subItem['title']),
                      )
                      .toList())
            ]),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: renderCats()),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Esto te puede servir para lo que quieres:

```
void main() {
  List listCats = [
   {
    'main_title' : 'MENS\'S APPAREL',
    'items' : [
      {
        'title': 'T-shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
      {
        'title': 'Shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    'main_title' : 'WOMEN APPAREL',
    'items' : [
      {
        'title': 'Officewear',
        'route' : '/',
      },
      {
        'title': 'Blouse & T-Shirts',
        'route' : '/',
      },
    ]
  },];

  listCats.forEach((item) {
    print(item['main_title']);

    if (item['items'] != null) {
      item['items'].forEach((subItem) {
        print(subItem);
      });
    }
  });

}
```